# ASP.NET SignalR chat display wrong avatar?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, signalr

I'm developing Chat module for HRM project using SignalR. Everything worked fine except the avatar and username do not match together on the user online list and in the chat box. For example, in the browser 1 , login username 1 is: thanhliem and avatar url liem.png, username 2 is: admin that get from broswer 2, but it used the same avatar url for different username. In the browser 2,login username 1 is admin and avatar url is admin.png , username 2 is thanhliem that get from browser 1 also use the same avatar url from username 1. So my question is: why signalR can pass correct usernames but   it went wrong with avatar url. 
Here is my detailed code:
1. Code behind:

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace BIX
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> dic = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
        }

        public void SendToSpecific(string name, string message, string to)
        {
            Clients.Caller.broadcastMessage(name, message);
            Clients.Client(dic[to]).broadcastMessage(name, message);
        }

        public void Notify(string name, string id)
        {
            if (dic.ContainsKey(name))
            {
                Clients.Caller.differentName();
            }
            else
            {
                dic.TryAdd(name, id);
                foreach (var entry in dic)
                {
                    Clients.Caller.online(entry.Key);
                }
                Clients.Others.enters(name);
            }
        }

        public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
        {
            var name = dic.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == Context.ConnectionId.ToString());
            string s;
            dic.TryRemove(name.Key, out s);
            return Clients.All.disconnected(name.Key);
        }
    }
}
```

and :

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using BIX.Business;

namespace BIX.Admins
{
    public partial class Chat : Page
    {
       protected static string userName { get; set; }
       protected static string userImage { get; set; }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                getUserInfo();
            }
        }

        private void getUserInfo()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Session["UserId"]))
            {
                Response.Redirect("/Account/Logout.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                userName = (string)Session["UserName"];
                var userId = (string)Session["UserId"];
                var listE = UsersService.Users_GetById(userId);
                userImage = listE[0].UserImage;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2: HTML and JS

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Chat.aspx.cs" Inherits="BIX.Admins.Chat" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <link href="../App_Themes/Admin/css/FBLikeChat.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <!-- chatjs requirements -->
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function() {
            startChatHub();
        });
        var nickname = "";
        var avatarurl = "";

        function startChatHub() {
            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;

            // Get the user name.
            nickname = "<%= userName %>";
            avatarurl = "<%= userImage %>";

            chat.client.online = function(name) {
                // Update list of users  
                if (name == nickname) {
                    $("#chat_body").append("<img src=" + avatarurl + " class=\"avatar\" /><div id=\"userlist\">" + name + "</div>");
                    $("#msg_head").append("<div id=userchat>" + name + "</div>");

                } else {
                    $("#chat_body").append("<img src=" + avatarurl + " class=\"avatar\" /><div id=\"userlist\">" + name + "</div>");
                    $("#users").append("<option value=\"" + name + "\">" + name + "</option>");
                }
            };
            chat.client.enters = function(name) {
                $("#msg_body").append("<div ><i>" + name + " joins the conversation</i></div>");
                $("#users").append("<option value=\"" + name + "\">" + name + "</option>");
                //$("#chat_body").append("<div id=userlist>" + name + "</div>");
                $("#chat_body").append("<img src=" + avatarurl + " class=\"avatar\" /><div id=\"userlist\">" + name + "</div>");
            };
            // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast chat messages.  
            chat.client.broadcastMessage = function(name, message) {
                //Interpret smileys  
                message = message.replace(":)", "<img src=\"/ChatJS/Images/Emoticons/smile-2.png\" class=\"smileys\" />");
                message = message.replace(":D", "<img src=\"/ChatJS/Images/Emoticons/smile-1.png\" />");
                message = message.replace(":o", "<img src=\"/ChatJS/Images/Emoticons/smile-6.png\" />");

                //display the message  
                //$("#msg_body").append("<div class=\"border\"><span style=\"color:orange\">" + name + "</span>: " + message + "</div>");
                $("#msg_body").append("<img src=" + avatarurl + " class=\"avatar\" />", message);
            };

            chat.client.disconnected = function(name) {
                //Calls when someone leaves the page  
                $("#msg_body").append("<div ><i>" + name + " leaves the conversation</i></div>");
                $("#chat_body div").remove(":contains('" + name + "')");
                jQuery(this).attr("src", "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==");
                $("#users option").remove(":contains('" + name + "')");
            };
            //scroll bar
            $(".chat_head").click(function() {
                $("#chat_body").slideToggle("slow");
            });
            $("#msg_head").click(function() {
                $(".msg_wrap").slideToggle("slow");
            });

            $(".close").click(function() {
                $(".msg_box").hide();
            });

            $("#userlist").click(function() {

                $(".msg_wrap").show();
                $(".msg_box").show();
            });

            // Start the connection.  
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
                //Calls the notify method of the server  
                chat.server.notify(nickname, $.connection.hub.id);
                $("#messagebox").keypress(function(e) {
                    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                        var msg = "<div id=msg_b>" + $("#messagebox").val() + "</div>";
                        $("#messagebox").val("");
                        if ($("#users").val() == "All") {
                            //Call the Send method on the hub.  
                            chat.server.send(nickname, msg);
                            $("#msg_body").scrollTop($("#msg_body")[0].scrollHeight);
                        } else {
                            chat.server.sendToSpecific(nickname, msg, $("#users").val());
                            //Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.   
                            $("#messagebox").val("").focus();
                            $("#msg_body").scrollTop($("#msg_body")[0].scrollHeight);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- FBchat -->
<div id="chat_box">
    <div class="chat_head"> Friends</div>
    <div id="chat_body">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="msg_box" style="right: 210px">
    <div id="msg_head">
        <div class="close" aria-hidden="true">x</div>
    </div>
    <div class="msg_wrap">
        <div id="msg_body">
            <div class="msg_push"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="msg_footer">
            <div style="float: right">
                <select id="users">
                    <option value="All">All</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <textarea id="messagebox" class="msg_input" placeholder="Type a message..."></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is the image for illustration:
[Chat window UI](http://i147.photobucket.com/albums/r305/liemoffline/Untitled_1.png)

[Chat window UI 2](http://i147.photobucket.com/albums/r305/liemoffline/Untitled2_1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code as the follow, hope it work:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

                $("#chat_body").slideToggle("slow");

                $(".msg_wrap").slideToggle("slow");
        });
        $(function () {
            startChatHub();
        });
        var nickname = "";
        var avatarurl = "";

        function startChatHub() {
            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;

            // Get the user name.
            nickname = "<%= userName %>";
            avatarurl = "<%= userImage %>";

            chat.client.online = function (name) {
                // Update list of users  
                if (name == nickname) {
                    $("#chat_body").append("<img src=" + avatarurl + " class=\"avatar\" /><div id=\"userlist\">" + name + "</div>");
                    $("#msg_head").append("<div id=userchat>" + name + "</div>");

                } else {
                    $("#chat_body").append("<img src=\"../Images/user.jpg\" class=\"avatar\" /><div id=\"userlist\">" + name + "</div>");
                    $("#users").append("<option value=\"" + name + "\">" + name + "</option>");
                }
            };
            chat.client.enters = function (name) {
                $("#msg_body").append("<div ><i>" + name + " signs in</i></div>");
                $("#users").append("<option value=\"" + name + "\">" + name + "</option>");
                //$("#chat_body").append("<div id=userlist>" + name + "</div>");
                $("#chat_body").append("<img src=\"../Images/user.jpg\" class=\"avatar\" /><div id=\"userlist\">" + name + "</div>");
            };
            // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast chat messages.  
            chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
                //Interpret smileys  
                message = message.replace(":)", "<img src=\"../Images/Emoticons/smile-2.png\" class=\"smileys\" />");
                message = message.replace(":D", "<img src=\"../Images/Emoticons/smile-1.png\" />");
                message = message.replace(":o", "<img src=\"../Images/Emoticons/smile-6.png\" />");
                var currentdate = new Date();
                var chattime = currentdate.getDate() + "/"
                + (currentdate.getMonth() + 1) + "/"
                + currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ "
                + currentdate.getHours() + ":"
                + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":"
                + currentdate.getSeconds();
                //display the message  
                $("#msg_body").append("<div class=\"border\"><span style=\"color:orange\">" + name + "</span>: " + " <span class='msg-time'>" + chattime + "</span>" + "</div>" + message);
                //$("#msg_body").append("<img src=" + avatarurl + " class=\"avatar\" />", message);
            };

            chat.client.disconnected = function (name) {
                //Calls when someone leaves the page  
                $("#msg_body").append("<div ><i>" + name + " signs out</i></div>");
                $("#chat_body div").remove(":contains('" + name + "')");
                $("#users option").remove(":contains('" + name + "')");
            };
            //scroll bar
            $(".chat_head").click(function () {
                $("#chat_body").slideToggle("slow");
            });
            $("#msg_head").click(function () {
                $(".msg_wrap").slideToggle("slow");
            });

            $(".close").click(function () {
                $(".msg_box").hide();
            });

            $("#userlist").click(function () {

                $(".msg_wrap").show();
                $(".msg_box").show();
            });

            // Start the connection.  
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                //Calls the notify method of the server  
                chat.server.notify(nickname, $.connection.hub.id);
                $("#messagebox").keypress(function (e) {
                    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                        var msg = "<div id=msg_b>" + $("#messagebox").val() + "</div>";
                        $("#messagebox").val("");
                        if ($("#users").val() == "All") {
                            //Call the Send method on the hub.  
                            chat.server.send(nickname, msg);
                            $("#msg_body").scrollTop($("#msg_body")[0].scrollHeight);
                        } else {
                            chat.server.sendToSpecific(nickname, msg, $("#users").val());
                            //Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.   
                            $("#messagebox").val("").focus();
                            $("#msg_body").scrollTop($("#msg_body")[0].scrollHeight);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        }

</script>
```

Comment: Instead of display Avatar , why do not use username when chatting, and we only display the right avatar for the current session and add a null image for other users. It is an alternation for your problem.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, you're right! Why I cannot find out this way.